# overloading operators of builtin types

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

While am writing some code as syntactic sugar like this implementation of the power-operator known in python and other languages, the operator definition is ok, but an expression with the operand(s) matching the operators signature yields an error, as the operators were never defined. Is there a way (compiler option) to implement new operators for builtin types?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

    template<typename t_Float>
struct PowerTmp {
    t_Float value;
};

PowerTmp<double> operator*(double f) {
    return {f};
};

double operator*(double l, PowerTmp<double> r) {
    return std::pow(l, r.value);
};

int main() {
    std::cout << 10.5 *PowerTmp<double>{2.0} << '\n';
    cout << 10.5 ** 2.0 << '\n'; //error
};
```

I am using mingw.

**EDIT**: clang does even not support the definition of the operator.

Comment: There is no `**` operator in C++, if you are expecting that to be exponentiation like in Python you should use `std::pow` or write your own function

Comment: @CoryKramer However, when using a user defined type instead of double and cast the numbers to this type, the power-operator defined here works (it is really two operators, the *-prefix operator and the multiplication-operator!)

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot overload an operator where the only arguments are built-in types. Even if that operator doesn't exist for said type.

What you can do is create an intermediary type. For example:

```
struct EnhancedDouble {
    double d;
};

struct PowPrecursor {
    double d;
};

PowPrecursor operator*(EnhancedDouble b) {
    return { b.d };
}

EnhancedDouble operator*(EnhancedDouble lhs, PowPrecursor rhs) {
    return { std::pow(lhs.d, rhs.d) };
}
```

You can even sugar this up a little more with a user defined literal.

```
EnhancedDouble operator""_ed(long double d) {
    return { (double)d };
}
```

Throw in an `operator<<` and you can do this:

```
std::cout << 4.0_ed ** 4.0_ed; // prints 256
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is impossible currently. You cannot overload operators for built-ins. Due to this, your first overload is illegal, as you're trying to define unary `operator*` for `double`. Not sure why gcc doesn't complain.

However, you can use UDL to "change" the type of the literal. Here's a simplified example for demonstration purposes:

```
struct Exponent { long double value; };
struct PowerDouble { long double value; };

Exponent operator""_exp(long double exponent) {
    return{exponent};
}

PowerDouble operator*(Exponent f) {
    return{f.value};
}

long double operator*(long double l, PowerDouble r) {
    return std::pow(l, r.value);
}

long double operator*(long double l, Exponent r) {
    return l * r.value;
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
std::cout << 10.5 ** 2._exp << '\n';
std::cout << 10.5 * 2._exp << '\n';
```

Comment: Note that with this, `10.5 * 2._exp` will also perform exponentiation. As will `10.5 ***** 2._exp`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You are right, fixed :) Thanks